# Как отфильтровать значения Map() в JS?

Tags: javascript, производительность

У меня есть Map(), как я могу проверить эту коллекцию, содержит ли она в себе элемент  корорый содержит определенный символ? Если другими словами, то например есть такой список: Максим, Иван, Дмитрий, Олег, Алексей. Пользователь вводит какой нибудь символ(например "К") мне надо записать в новый список только те которые содержат этот символ. Т.е. должны записяться Максим и Алексей

```
        var myMap = new Map();
        var j = 0;
        $('li', "#userlist").each(function () {            
            var user = this.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();
            myMap.set(j, user);
            array[j] = user;
            j++;
        });

var input = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();
var filteredList;
```

Comment: причем тут сортировка? в чем смысл `Map`? почему не просто массив?

Comment: @Grundy Как причем, мне нужно вписать отсортированные значения в новый Map. В задании написано использовать Map  :)

Comment: Выбрать из коллекции несколько элементов, по условию - это не сортировка. Сортировка, это расположение элементов внутри коллекции в определенном порядке

Comment: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) - Это словарь, у которого есть ключи и значения. Непонятно, в чем ты хочешь искать введенный символ, в ключах или значениях.

Comment: @Grundy искать нужно в значениях.  Заголовок исправил. Спасибо

Comment: Добавь пример твоего `Map`, код инициализации, чтобы было понятно что где лежит

Comment: @Grundy Добавил

Comment: вы автокомплит что ли реализуете?

Comment: @etki Так точно :)

Comment: Бросьте вы это да воспользуйтесь услугами БД/поискового движка. Там ей-богу до мало-мальски приемлемого уровня такие дебри, какие вам и не снились.

Comment: @etki Да у меня есть огромный список пользователей на странице, и я не делаю большой фильтр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), в данном случае не нужен, так как `Map` с целочисленным ключом - это обычный массив, у которого отсутствует большинство *привычных* функций.

В случае с массивом можно примерить метод [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var filteredList = array.filter(el => el.indexOf(input) > -1);
```

В случае с `Map`, есть несколько вариантов

1. пробежаться по `Map` и удалить ненужные с помощью методов [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) и [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/delete)
2. с помощью [spread оператора](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) получить массив ключей/значений, отфильтровать этот массив, и заново создать `Map`, например: `var m = new Map([...oldMap].filter(el=> el[1].indexOf(input)>-1))`

Comment: Огромное спасибо !